# ASP.NET MVC 5 SignInAsync() returns a not authenticated user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this default code in my AccountController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

When I login with a normal user with one role so everything is fine. But when I login with a user which has 3 roles, so this user is after the SignInAsync() function not authenticated and has no roles. About one hour ago everything worked fine, but now I can't get my user with 3 roles authenticated.

Does anybody have a hint for me?